# Receive email read receipt in mail()

Tags: php

I am trying to get a confirmation when the receiver opens/reads the email. I have tried the following three ways but none has worked. I need this done with `mail()` function, not PHPMailer.

The email does get sent successfully, but no confirmation comes to `$from` email. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$from = "sender@gmail.com";
$email_header = "X-Confirm-Reading-To: $from\r\n";
$email_header .= "Return-Receipt-To: $from\r\n";
$email_header .= "Disposition-Notification-To: $from\r\n";
$sending_mail = mail("receiver@gmail.com","test subject","test message",$email_header);
```

Comment: Many mail systems now do not send read receipts. There's nothing you can do to force them to do so.

Comment: Use HTML message and use `<img>` tag that point to your PHP to collect data and output image. Example `<img src="https://mydomain.tld/read-email.jpg?recipient=xxx">` but this is still not 100% work depend on email client.

Comment: @vee Thanks but can you explain how/why this works?

Comment: Because if email client supported HTML message, the `<img>` element will call to file on your domain/website (in `src=".."`) and you can use mod-rewrite to change from **read-email.jpg** to php file. In the php file, you can collect data send via method GET `$_GET['recipient']` and then render image content with correct `content-type`.

Answer (score 3):

Many [email clients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_tracking) does not return a read receipt such as [Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9413651?hl=en) (except Gmail for work or school). Some IMAP based email client marks your message as read, but doesn't open it. (Read more in the [link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9413651?hl=en)).

If the email client supported HTML message, you can use `<img>` element to do the trick. However, this is not always 100% work because some client does support HTML contents but use proxy to detect the image link.

Your HTML message will contain an image like this.

```
<img src="https://mydomain.tld/email-read-reciept.jpg?recipient=user@hotmail.com" alt="">
```

- Replace `https://mydomain.tld` with yours and please use the real URL so that email client can work properly.
- Replace `user@hotmail.com` to your recipient email address.

On your server, Add this **.htaccess** contents to make it support mod-rewrite from fake JPG to PHP file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^email-read-reciept\.(png|jpg|gif)$    read-recipient.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Create **read-recipient.php** file for process the data from email client (`$_GET['recipient']`) and then render the real image.

```
<?php
// get recipient
$recipient = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'recipient', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
// do something with this recipient.
$writeFile = 'recipient.txt';
file_put_contents($writeFile, var_export($recipient, true) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

// finish for processing recipient open the message.
// send out image contents from real image file.
$imageFile = 'image.jpg';
$finfo = new finfo();

$mimetype = $finfo->file($imageFile, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
unset($finfo);

header('content-type: ' . $mimetype);
echo file_get_contents($imageFile);
exit();// done.
```

You should have an image file for this. It maybe just white image 1x1 pixel or larger to avoid detection from email client.

[image: read recipiet]
Tested and work on Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you would like to know, whether client opened your email or not, you can send him email, that contains iframe with a link you your site, like that:

```
<iframe src="[link_to_your_site]/email_opened_notififer.php?email_id=[email_id]" width="0" height="0">
</iframe>
```

Your `email_opened_notififer.php` should look something like that:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['email_id']))
{
    $from = "sender@gmail.com";
    $email_header = "X-Confirm-Reading-To: $from\r\n";
    $email_header .= "Return-Receipt-To: $from\r\n";
    $email_header .= "Disposition-Notification-To: $from\r\n";
    $sending_mail = mail($from, "Email status upgrade", "Email " . $_GET['email_id'] . " has been opened",$email_header);
}
?>
```

But this method would work only if you would live like in 2002, cause almost every modern mail client would just block iframe, or strip it from arguments.

Comment: Thanks but then how come Streak for Gmail (Chrome extension) does it for all my mails that I send, without fail? How come all email clients provide read receipt to Streak?

Comment: I guess they are doing it via google admin console, so it probably works only with gmail.

Comment: no it works for other email clients as well.