# How to verify an email by the making the button working properly?

Tags: html, email, gmail, verification

I am working on an email verification functionality. The problem is that I want if someone clicks on the  **Confirm email address** button then an alert should be shown up or a user should be notified the button is clicked but it does not perform any actions on my Gmail account.

What are the ways to make it work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <center><h1>We're glad you're here</h1></center>
    <center>We just want to confirm it's you.<br><br></center>
    <center>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">
            Click to confirm your email address
        </button>
    <center>
    <center><br>If you didn't create a proctl account, just delete this email.</center>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
          alert("I am an alert box!");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Most of email providers such as Gmail did not allow you to run JS. Even the CSS have limitations.

Comment: @vee Is there any other alternative to it? What should I choose?

Comment: I've [answered and tested this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70236290/receive-email-read-receipt-in-mail/70249578#70249578) before but currently I can't make sure that is it still working.

Comment: Or just use normal link `<a href="...">...</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

Due to security concerns, Javascript is not supported in email messages. So instead of verifying it by js `onclick` event, you can insert an HTML link to it.

Ref: [Is JavaScript supported in an email message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054315/is-javascript-supported-in-an-email-message)